# Email Form to specific email addresses based on values selected in MultiSelect Box

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, email

I've created a HTML contact form which connects to a MySQL database to populate some options into a multiselect field.

I now need to send an email to a specific people depending on what values are selected in the MultiSelect field. But I can't figure out how to define the email addresses based on the selection.

This is the code I've used to populate the multiselect field.

```
$sql="SELECT addr1, city, status FROM listings WHERE status<>'Hidden' ";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$options=""; 

 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

     $addr1=$row["addr1"]; 
     $city=$row["city"];
     $status=$row["status"];
     $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$addr1\">".$addr1 . ', ' . $city . ' - ' . $status; 
 }

<select multiple name="unit" id="unit" size="10" validate="required:true, rangelength:[1,5]">
    <?=$options ?> 
</select>
```

My Database structure looks like this

```
addr1        city        status        manager
address      somecity    available     John Citizen
addresstwo   city2       not available Jack Citizen
addressthree city3       available     Jill Citizen
```

So when someone selects John Citizen and Jill Citizen, the email should be sent to those two people.
I will also need to declare the email addresses for these two people via PHP variables. 
The Form will then be sent with this Code. (This code is in a different PHP file that the Form Action calls)

```
mail($emailaddresses,$subject,$html,"From: info@#####\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n");
```

}

Is anyone able to give me some pointers? I have tried many things but can't get the selection working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Give your multiselect form field a name that ends with [] (e.g. name="unit[]"). In PHP when you submit the form that will generate an array which will be populated with the selected items ($_POST("unit")). You can then implode() the array, separating the email addresses with a comma (or semi-colon -- I never remember offhand which one delimits emails in the php mail() function). Then just drop this string of address in your mail() call.